# object is null in angularjs using $resource

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

In my resources i have following code

```
app.factory('myResource', function ($resource, $http) {
    var resource = $resource('http://localhost:1234/api/:pg/:obj', {
        pg: '@pg',
        obj: '@obj'
    },
        {
            'put': {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            'get': { method: 'GET' },
            'save': { method: 'POST' },
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            'remove': { method: 'DELETE' },
            'delete': { method: 'DELETE' }
        }
        );
    return resource;
});
```

and in controller i use like

```
            var param = { pg: 'MyTask', obj: taskModel }
            $scope.TaskId = myResource.put(param);
```

and on debugging data is fine in `obj` but getting null in model

```
public HttpResponseMessage put(MyTask model)
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your resource is configured to serialize @pg and @obj into URI.

> $resource('http://localhost:1234/api/:pg/:obj', {

But WEBAPI sees MyTask object(complex object) and expects it to be from request body.

Either change client side to include "obj" data into request body or change server-side to get model from uri using webapi attributes. It all depends on complexity of "obj" information.